# How can I get vue-file-agent to work (Vue 3)

Tags: file-upload, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I would like to upload files (xlsx, pdf, image) in a Vue 3 app Options API. Now trying to use [vue-file-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-file-agent) for that purpose.

If I use the code provided in section Basic Usage I get error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend') at Module.fb15 (vue-file-agent.umd.js:718:130). See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-file-agent-basic-lpvhfy)

So now I try the [Gmail Inspired Demo](https://safrazik.github.io/vue-file-agent/docs/) (at the bottom of that webpage). Copied that in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-file-agent-gmail-9g6v4f) and there I only get message 'Invalid Host header' in the browser-preview.

How can I get started with the basic and the gmail-style example?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Vue 3 version of the component developed by another developer based on vue-file-agent. It is available here - https://github.com/boindil/vue-file-agent-next